# What does argMax do with an array as axis?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tensorflow.js

In the tutorial for tensorflowjs, for [recognizing handwritten numbers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#6), the code uses:

```
const labels = testData.labels.argMax([-1]);
```

However, it looks like `Tensor<Rank.R2>.argMax` takes an axis as argument, which is a number (also makes sense). Typescript accordingly complains:

[image: wrong type]

What is happening here? Is this just a mistake in the tutorial, and `argMax` just converts the one element array to number, getting what it needs? Is there some convention or deeper meaning here?

As generally, argmax operations should imho be commutative, it could just interpret e.g. `.argMax([-1, -2])` as `.argMax(-1).argMax(-1)`, however, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ts typing of `axis` indicates that it is a number, thus the complain of tslint.
Looking at the source code, the axis is later pushed into an array with the following

```
[].concat(axis)
```

Whether it is a number or an array of a single number, it will return the same thing. However it is not yet supported an array of multiple axis.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the tutorial is using some slightly unclean code then, and it should just be `-1` instead of `[-1]`. When being a complete beginner at something, i just tend to double-check, before fixing tutorial code.